# Extract By Mask gives different result (and WARNING 000622) in ArcPy than from tool dialog?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, spatial-analyst, extract-by-mask

I'm using ArcMap 10.3.1

When I use the gp tool to extract by mask, I get the correct result with any area outside the mask set as NoData.

When I do the same thing in a script, I end up with cells with other values outside the mask.
[image: gp result then script result]

Note the values within the mask are correct, the stretching is different because the black cells outside the mask have a value of -32768 (the minimum value in a 16 bit signed raster).

It looks like something to do with tiling?

Note when using the gp tool, I get the message "WARNING 000632: Datum conflict between map and output." I don't know if this is relevant?

Below is my script.

Any ideas?

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import sa as sa
ws = 'c:/temp/test/'
arcpy.env.workspace = ws
outMask = sa.ExtractByMask('band2.tif', 'Clip109071.shp')
outMask.save('band2clipped.tif')
```

Comment: Set environment extent, snap raster and cell size 'equal' parent raster and output to grid stored in folder.

Comment: Thats very interesting. Im guessing that you have reprojected the image on the fly, then created a mask shp. The Shp would then have a different datum. 

My next guess is then that using the GP tool by picking from  a layer in the dataframe actually uses a reprojected temp file for that layer, not the original file. So no conflict, but the script uses the original and so there is a conflict.

I cannot find any reference to this on the web, but it would be easy to test - run the GP tool but select from the original file not the layer. I would be really interested to hear what happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I repeated your script line by line from Python window.

OUTPUT:
[image]

I removed 2 lines in your script and added:

```
d=arcpy.Describe('Clip109071.shp')
arcpy.env.extent=d.extent
outMask = sa.ExtractByMask('band2.tif', 'Clip109071.shp')
outMask.save('asGrid')
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

is what one expects to see.

So exporting to grid format fixed the problem.